# center a div and make it scrollable inside a fixed container

Tags: css

I am implementing a modal with only css. So in the end I have a fixed position container and a div inside it. What I want to accomplish is the div to be always centered inside the fixed container and to have scroll if the whole content of the div is not visible (if You resize the browser). Here is my code:

html:

```
<div>
<a href="#openModal">open</a>
  <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div class="container">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
} 

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.container {
        position: relative;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        background: #fff;
        margin: 10% auto;
        overflow-y: scroll;

    }
```

Comment: What should be centered and how?

Answer (score 0):

To center the div's inside the `container` div you have to add a `text-align: center;`. To have a scrollbar in your div, I guess your `container` div again, you have to add a height to your div. Then, you can use a `overflow: scroll;` to add the scrollbar.

```
.container {
        position: relative;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        background: #fff;
        margin: 10% auto;
        overflow: scroll;
        text-align: center;
        height: 350px;
    }
```